# Create common horizon setup for application which is uploaded on multiple severs

Tags: redis, laravel-5.8, horizon

I have one application which is uploaded on multiple servers (if in case one serve get down). is it possible to create common horizon setup for multiple server? If yes please share configuration or documentation url.